# does implementing new relic affect page load time

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform, web-performance

If we install new relic on a linux server, will it cause a delay in page loading time?
I have installed new relic and it seems that it is causing some delay in page loading time.

Can anyone confirm me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/will-newrelic-server-monitoring-affect-my-server-performance/4051:

> We do extensive testing and estimate our overhead impact to be roughly
>   5% (+/- a few points) as it relates to CPU impact on the box and
>   application response time. This is based on a number of different
>   frameworks and load patterns we test with, as well as our default
>   instrumentation (byte code probes). Given that the Server Monitors do
>   much less instrumentation than our language agents, and mostly just
>   query data, we would expect this number to be even lower. Since every
>   application and server is different, we always encourage customers to
>   run their own tests in a pre-production environment to validate
>   overhead and let us know if they encounter anything different. Based
>   on our current traffic (datacenter bandwidth divided by number of
>   agents reporting), we calculate each agent consumes an average of
>   0.0008 Mb/s (megabytes/second) ~ 838 bytes/second, or roughly 50K bytes/minute.

So yes, there is probably a measurable effect but it should be small.